# Where is the Lexicon Receptacle?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So right now I'm doing the Discerning The Transmundane, and the Lexicon Receptacle is not there. I've reloaded my game and everything and nothing has worked. What can I do without having to restart my entire game?

Comment: Would you be more specific? Can you take a picture and show us? We may be able to solve it if you do. If you can't, tell us in detail.

Comment: The lexicon is huge and takes up an entire room, and as far as I know I've never heard of it not being available. What do you mean it's not there?

Comment: @ChaseC perhaps the person was lost during the quest and couldn't find the place. However, we can only find out what he/she means if there is an image of this.

Comment: Most dwarven ruins have a "end of ruins" boss.  Usually a Centurion (was for me).  After you beat this boss, you go to the room behind them, usually leads out and another exit to Blackreach.  Got through Blackreach, get to  Tower of Mzark.  You then enter the Lexicon.  http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Discerning_the_Transmundane

Comment: @ChaseC Isn't the lexicon just the cube? It sounds like the post you stick the cube in isn't there.

Comment: @DCShannon If I'm remembering correctly, the Lexicon is the big multi-dimensional circle thing that the Elder Scroll sits inside of. You have to hit the 3 buttons to get it to line up correctly and it dispenses the Elder Scroll to you.

Comment: @ChaseC It's the cube: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Lexicon

Comment: @DCShannon I am under the impression that the question is asking about the Lexicon Receptacle, not the Lexicon cube. What is missing is the actual thing to put it in, not the item in the inventory. I could be wrong, but that was just my impression.

Comment: @ChaseC That's my impression, which I'm indicating as opposed to your impression that he is saying the whole room is missing. It's just the receptacle for the cube, which is a post. Look at your comment from the 27th "takes up an entire room...what do you mean it's not there". You and Jim seemed to be under the impression this question was ambiguous. I'm trying to clarify that the receptacle is just a post next to the control panel. There's a picture on that Lexicon page, although I think it's from Unfathomable Depths instead of Elder Knowledge.

Comment: @Isuka It doesn't matter which one was asked earlier. The other question has more details, has pictures, and has answers. It wouldn't make sense to close it as a duplicate of this one, from a utility standpoint.

Comment: @Isuka The mod isn't part of the question, it's just part of one of the answers. I'm fine with that, but I could see leaving it open under our "don't close duplicates if the other answer isn't helpful" policy. In this instance, I would wait until the asker indicated that the other wasn't useful, as they look the same to me at the moment. Vote as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you picked up the elder scroll before you were supposed to I've seen that glitch a few times. Scroll has to be in the machine, and the blank lexicon placed near the set of switches. Should be good to go after that.

Comment: "the blank lexicon placed near the set of switches" That would be in the receptacle, which is what the asker is saying is missing.